# When I for loop through an ArrayList with If condicions the items before the searched ones get displayed

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist, while-loop

I wanted to create a program which is Object Oriented, that consists of students stored in an ArrayList in the Grade class. Every Student has a name, a surname and an age. So what I wanted to accomplish is getting back all the information of one student in the ArrayList in the console by using a Scanner. So I basically store the user given value and compare it in an if-Statement with the names or surnames in the ArrayList using a for-loop. If the passed name doesn't equal one of the names in the ArrayList, a message says the person does not exist in this grade.

It works but if I loop through the ArrayList to get person on index 2 for instance, the message that the person doesn't exist in this grade pops up for index 0 and 1 and I dont want that.

I'm from Germany, thats why most of the stuff is written in German. This is the code:

```
package package_Fachklassen;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Startklasse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Schoolclass sk1, sk2;
        sk1 = new Schoolclass("WG 13-1");
        sk2 = new Schoolclass("WG 13-2");

        //Klasse 13-1

        Student s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10;
        s1 = new Student ("Gonzalo", "Cofre Real", 18, sk1);
        s2 = new Student ("Swaastika", "Yogeswaran", 20, sk1);
        s3 = new Student ("Derin", "Sipahi", 19, sk1);
        s4 = new Student ("Henry", "Reinhold", 19, sk1);
        s5 = new Student ("Sara", "Perkovic", 19, sk1);
        s6 = new Student ("Honia", "Aref", 19, sk1);
        s7 = new Student ("Finn", "Bolheimer", 17, sk1);
        s8 = new Student ("Karoline", "Garkos", 18, sk1);
        s9 = new Student ("Hannah", "Hirth", 18, sk1);
        s10 = new Student ("Sarah", "Schwarz", 18, sk1);

        sk1.addStudent (s1);
        sk1.addStudent (s2);
        sk1.addStudent (s3);
        sk1.addStudent (s4);
        sk1.addStudent (s5);
        sk1.addStudent (s6);
        sk1.addStudent (s7);
        sk1.addStudent (s8);
        sk1.addStudent (s9);
        sk1.addStudent (s10);

        //Klasse 13-2

        Student  ss1, ss2, ss3, ss4, ss5, ss6;
        ss1 = new Student ("Cem", "Yildiz", 19, sk2);
        ss2 = new Student ("Fathima", "Baba", 19, sk2);
        ss3 = new Student ("Sanjie", "Bislimi", 19, sk2);
        ss4 = new Student ("Jasmine", "Jaffari", 19, sk2);
        ss5 = new Student ("Hannah", "Arent", 19, sk2);
        ss6 = new Student ("Niklas", "Genf", 18, sk2);

        sk2.addStudent (ss1);
        sk2.addStudent (ss2);
        sk2.addStudent (ss3);
        sk2.addStudent (ss4);
        sk2.addStudent (ss5);
        sk2.addStudent (ss6);



        while(true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Which class does your student visit?");
            String k_input= scan.nextLine();
            if(k_input.equals(sk1.getDescription())) {
                System.out.println("For which student in class 13-1 are you looking for?");
                String n_input = scan.nextLine();
                for(int i = 0; i < sk1.getListLength(); i++) {
                    if(n_input.equals(sk1.getStudent(i).getName()) || n_input.equals(sk1.getStudent(i).getSurname())) {
                        System.out.println("Your student:");
                        System.out.println(" " + sk1.getStudent(i).getName());
                        System.out.println(" " + sk1.getStudent(i).getSurname());
                        System.out.println(" " + sk1.getSchueler(i).getAge());
                        break;
                    }
                    else if(){
                        System.out.println("Student does not exist in this class!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Which class does your student visit?
- (User-Input) WG 13-1
- For which student in class 13-1 are you looking for?
- (User-Input) Derin
- Student does not exist in this class!
- Student does not exist in this class!
- Your Student:
- Derin
- Sipahi
- 19
- Which class does your student visit?

Comment: You should change:else if(){ to else instead. It would be easier to help you if the code could be run locally and the function names are in English.

Comment: Changing else if(){ to just else would do the same, as it would still print the not found message for each iteration when the student doesn't match.

Comment: You should consider changing || to && since you have a logical error. You could end up with the wrong student if there are multiple students with the same name or surname. Still, this issue will arise as well since you have a break in the loop if your student has the same first name and surname you will only print the first you find and then skip the second one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How you could solve the issue is to move out the missing student print outside the for loop, to just print it when there is no student found.

Your issue is that for each student you don't find you print missing students until you find a student. My suggestion below is far from the most sophisticated solution.

```html
Boolean StudentMissing = True
for(int i = 0; i < sk1.getListenLaenge(); i++) {
  if(n_input.equals(sk1.getSchueler(i).getName()) || n_input.equals(sk1.getSchueler(i).getNachname())) {
    System.out.println(" " + sk1.getSchueler(i).getAlter());
    StudentMissing = False
    break;
  }
}
if(StudentMissing){
  System.out.println("Schüler existiert nicht oder ist nicht in dieser Klasse!");
}
```

Comment: I knew that it had to do sth with the else if statement. Thank you very much Fredrik, I applied ur suggestion to my program and it actually worked. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It's doing that because every time through your loop, if it wasn't the student you were looking for, it prints what you told it to in your else statement.

What you need to do, is don't add an 'else' at all. Instead, when you find the student inside of your 'if' ... store it into a variable to analyze later after you're completely out of your loop. Remember to declare this storage variable before your loop so you have scope to it after when your aren't in the loop anymore. It could be a string that builds your whole answer you were sending to the output ... but in this case we are storing it to display later.

Set it to null when you declare it.

Then, when you are totally done your loop ... break or not ... you test that variable, and that's where you can tell if it's found anything or not (if it's null still or not.) You know that by testing if it was still null, or if it got filled with an answer while in the loop.

If it has an answer in it (not null still) ... that's when you output it to the user.

And if was still null ... that's when you tell the user you didn't find any such student.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is, that your else clause contains another if statement (`else if ()`) that is always true and gets executed. In your example, you're looking for student 3 "Derin", which does not match the first student (Gonzalo), so the else case gets executed printing that the student doesn't exist. The same happens for the second student, and then the third student is found and the for loop exits. When you choose another student, e.g. the fifth in the list, the not found message would be printed four times and then the message for the found student. You'll get the maximum number of not found messages, when you enter a name that doesn't match any of the students.

When you change your code just to `else { ... }` (as mentioned above) the same will happen. It gets much easier, when you do the two things that you want to accomplish in two steps: First, try to find the student and remember it by using a variable of type `Schueler`, then print the student / the error message. To do this, you need to move the output of the student / the error message outside the for loop. Here's the fixed code:

```
Schueler foundStudent = null;
for(int i = 0; i < sk1.getListenLaenge(); i++) {
    if (n_input.equals(sk1.getSchueler(i).getName()) || n_input.equals(sk1.getSchueler(i).getNachname())) {
        foundStudent = sk1.getSchueler(i);
        break;
} 

if (foundStudent != null) {
    System.out.println("Ihr Schüler:");
    System.out.println(" " + foundStudent.getName());
    System.out.println(" " + foundStudent.getNachname());
    System.out.println(" " + foundStudent.getAlter());
} else {       
    System.out.println("Schüler existiert nicht oder ist nicht in dieser Klasse!");
}
```

Comment: Hey Ralf, I tried it this way, just that the in the end the console would just say the student doesn't exist till the person I'm looking for and wont even display the students information at all. But still thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, Gonzalo, that was a mistake on my part due to copy & paste. In the print part, the foundStudent needs to be printed. I fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question was fairly simple and thanks to a user suggestion, the program finally worked as it should.

I basically had to get rid of the else statement after my if clause and set up a boolean variable before that. When the if statment is true, the students information is displayed in the console and the boolean variable is declared false, so the questioning starts again.
Then I had to write a new if statement for the case of the boolean variable being true and displaiying the error message.

Here is the new code:

```
while(true) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welche Klasse besucht der gesuchte Schüler?");
        String k_input= scan.nextLine();
        if(k_input.equals(sk1.getBezeichnung()) || k_input.equals(sk2.getBezeichnung())) {
            System.out.println("Welchen SChüler aus Klasse 13-1 suchen Sie?");
            String n_input = scan.nextLine();
            boolean studentmissing = true;
            for(int i = 0; i < sk1.getListenLaenge(); i++) {
                if(n_input.equals(sk1.getSchueler(i).getName()) || n_input.equals(sk1.getSchueler(i).getNachname())) {
                    studentmissing = false;
                    System.out.println("Ihr Schüler:");
                    System.out.println(" " + sk1.getSchueler(i).getName());
                    System.out.println(" " + sk1.getSchueler(i).getNachname());
                    System.out.println(" " + sk1.getSchueler(i).getAlter());
                    break;
                }}
                if(studentmissing) {
                    System.out.println("Schüler existiert nicht oder ist nicht in dieser Klasse!");
                    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
                }
```